# Spring Boot Yml произвольные конфигурации

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yml

На просторах интернета все время видит пример как переделывают application.properties в application.yml

У меня есть несколько конфигурационных файлов, которые независимы и делать из них один большой конфиг неправильно

Spring легко подгружает application.yml, а мои конфиги он так грузить не хочет

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")//работает
@PropertySource("classpath:initiators.yml")//не работает
```

Существует ли простое решение грузить произвольные конфиги в yml?

Comment: spring profile не подходит?

Comment: 2ray а подробнее можно?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot из коробки ищет конфигурации в файлах c `application.properties` или `application.yml`.
Если вам не нравится `application.properties` - вы можете сменить имя, но при запуске надо будет это указать вручную

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Больше есть [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Для работы с разными профилями Вам надо создать разные файл с конфигурациями.
Например, вы можете иметь конфигурации для prod сервера и для dev(локальной разработки) - тогда создайте файл `application-dev.properties` для dev.

Укажите профили в плагине

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <profiles>
                    <profile>dev</profile>
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Когда надо испьзовать конфигурации для dev с `application-dev.properties` - запускайте проект с `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` или в укажите профиль явно в IDE.

Comment: Вопрос скорее не в том где он ищет СВОИ конфиги а в том что мне надо чтоб он мне по требованию мои конфиги вытаскивал из файлов, так что Вы видимо не так поняли мой вопрос

Comment: тогда вам надо испольовать профили

Comment: Если у Вас есть вариант как это делать - будте добры, приведите пример в виде кода, буду очень благодарен